# List content not showing in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am building an application in ASP.NET for an auction with a list that pulls data from a database and shows it in ListBox. I have `Auction.cs`:

```
namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class Auction
    {
        public string Productname { get; set; }
        public string Lastbidder { get; set; }
        public int Bidvalue { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ProductName: " + Productname + "\nLastbidder: " + Lastbidder + "\nBidvalue: " + Bidvalue;
        }
    }

    public class AuctionService
    {
        private List<Auction> listaAukcija = new List<Auction>();

        public List<Auction> ListaAukcija
        {
            get { return listaAukcija; }
            set { listaAukcija = value; }
        }

        public void getAll()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=JOVAN-PC;database=aukcija_jovan_gajic;integrated security=true;"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT a.id AS aid, p.name AS pn, u.name AS un, a.lastbid AS alb FROM auctions a JOIN products p ON a.productid = p.id JOIN users u ON a.lastbider = u.id";

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    listaAukcija.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Auction auction = new Auction();

                        if (reader["aid"] as int? != null)
                        {
                            auction.Productname = reader["pn"] as string;
                            auction.Lastbidder = reader["un"] as string;
                            auction.Bidvalue = (int)reader["alb"];
                        }

                        listaAukcija.Add(auction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `DbBroker.cs`:

```
namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class DbBroker
    {
        AuctionService aukcija = new AuctionService();

        public void executeQuery()
        {
            aukcija.getAll();
        }

        public void getArr()
        {
            string[] lista = aukcija.ListaAukcija.ConvertAll(obj => obj.ToString()).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine (string.Join("\n", lista));
        }  
    }
}
```

and a page called `Home.aspx` with code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DbBroker dbb = new DbBroker();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Label3.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
                dbb.executeQuery();
                dbb.getArr();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Home.aspx` should look something like this: 
[image]

But there is no text in the ListBox. I assume there is an error as the data from the list does not find its way to the ListBox. But no error is shown in Visual Studio. I checked the code a couple of times but I still can't find where the problem is. Can someone help me find what is causing the problem?

Comment: drop a breakpoint in your getArr() function and step through it to verify you're getting the results you expect from your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `dbb.getArr()` but you aren't actually doing anything with it. You need to bind the values you retrieve to your ListBox, not just write them to the screen.

Something along these lines should at least point you in the right direction. First, return the `string[]` from `getArr()`.

```
public string[] getArr()
{
    string[] lista = aukcija.ListaAukcija.ConvertAll(obj => obj.ToString()).ToArray();
    return lista;
}
```

Then set that string array as the DataSource to your ListBox and bind it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label3.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();

        dbb.executeQuery();
        string[] lista = dbb.getArr();

        listbox.DataSource = lista;
        listbox.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i haven't been available for a couple of days. This solved part of my problem, now i get error that says "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'name'." I am guessing this has to do something with my `CommandText`, but i am not sure how to bind it different way, i am not very versatile with `ASP.NET`.

Comment: It could also be that you have the `DataTextField` or the `DataValueField` set as "name". But it is hard to know because you haven't shown us your ListBox markup.

Comment: Oh, both of them are. I believe i should change both of them?

Comment: You could probably just remove them. You are binding just a simple array of strings. Those two properties are more meant for binding things such as DataTables that have multiple columns of data. At that point you could explicitly say to use the column called "name" as the text to show on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, figured it myself just now. Code now works, thanks for every advice given, they really helped me.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.